# How can I remove trailing whitespace only on changed lines in a pre-commit git hook?

Tags: git

I've seen a number of solutions suggested, but nearly all of them strip whitespace from the entire file if it's been changed, which is not an option. I have also tried:

```
git diff -w --no-color | git apply --cached
```

but it doesn't seem to work either.  I am using git version 1.6.3.1 and cannot update it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
git diff --cached --no-color > stage.diff && git apply --index -R stage.diff && git apply --index --whitespace=fix stage.diff && rm -f stage.diff
```

Comment: It took me entirely too long to figure out that the `git apply` should happen at the root directory or it won't work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on partially stages files (Git 1.9.2 on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have such a script handy, but I guess a good starting point is the sample pre-commit hook that ships with git (before it was converted to `diff --check`).
At least it only warns about added lines.

[gitweb view of pre-commit script](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample;h=71c10f25f485f4a995f4617a5fa7b0e424fcaae8;hb=ba2d0f4f35beffbf715ca652d5b36df8c0ad5ceb)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but I've got `git ws` aliased to `git rebase --whitespace=fix`

You can set up a similar alias by running

```
git config --global alias.ws 'rebase --whitespace=fix'
```

That will take any any commits that you haven't pushed yet and reapply them after having fixed the whitespace on only the lines that you've changed.